# facebook share error: "method" is a required parameter for FB.ui()

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

the headline says everything. I get always this error:
"method" is a required parameter for FB.ui(). But method is set to 'feed'

Is it because i currently working local on my machine and not on a really server??
App is also registered in facebook.

Any idea?

```
<span id='share'>SHARE</span>   
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: '2907534********', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#share').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
                    link: ' http://www.hyperarts.com/',
                    picture: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/external-xfbml/share-image.gif',
                    caption: 'This is the content of the "caption" field.',
                    description: 'This is the content of the "description" field, below the caption.',
                    message: ''
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like an issue with your application since any of sharing options doesn't work with your APP_ID (taken from site specified by `link`) Please ensure your application configured correctly and not blocked.

Answer (score 2):

The `$('#share').click(function(e){` section of code should go into the window.fbAsynchInit call to ensure the framework is loaded prior to assign a click event to something that utilizes the FB.

Answer (score 1):

I tested that very same code with my own app ID and it worked fine for me. The only difference is that I changed name, caption, and description to just be 'This', and I fixed a syntax issue at the end.

Are you sure this bit of code is the source of your error?

Comment: yes i also just copied this example out of an tutorial... what was this for an syntax issue?? 
You tested it local or on an live server??

Answer (score 0):

- you must be online on server ( really server )
- if you didn't have Facebook id in this line 
      FB.init({appId: '2907534********', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
   you must have one from this url : https://developers.facebook.com/
   or search in how to create facebook app 
   an example for ( how to create facebook app )
  hyperarts.com/blog/how-to-create-facebook-application-to-get-an-app-id-for-your-website/
- but if you already have facebook id and already know how to create app , you must put the code in the top , on the same file that you put on facebook canvas ,

as for example if you insert in canvas ( https://www.example.com/test.php ) 
and you must put this code at test.php

I hope your problem will be solved really soon!

Comment: check this url may be help you : http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-share-button-iframe-tab-applications/